# World chests loot

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I notice that there are lots of chests in the world which seem to spawn all the time, like the one opposite the Jedi Temple up the hill, in the tent. They seem to have random loot in and respawn.

Can you just camp them and loot them the whole time? Or is the respawn time long to prevent this?

Comment: No references to back this up, but anecdotally: Yes they do respawn. The respawn rate for them is low though; at least, compared to the item quality IMO. I get random purple drops off of common mobs more than I do world loot boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are some 'safe' chests. You could camp them for some easy bucks.

However, waiting a minute (or whatever the respawn timer is) for 100 credits seems me to be a waste of time.

Questing yields the most credits and experience per time, by far. There are a lot of daily repeatable quests, so I doubt you'll run out of quests.